# missing required source folder .link_to_grails_plugins/jquery-1.7.1/grails-app/i18n

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

My project compiled fine without any problems. I went out of Eclipse and went back inside and get this error. These folders do not exist in my project. I do not think are part of Grails, it appears that the STS creates them. What is the problem?

STS 2.9, Grails 2.0.1

Thank you very much advanced

[image]

Comment: thanks for asking this.  I had the same problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Right-click on the project node in the project tree and select Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies. It will reconfigure the classpath and source folders based on the installed plugins.